# I want to hide(using program) collapse all, view menu and Link with editor option available in project explorer for my eclipse Product

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna

I want to hide(using program) collapse all, view menu and Link with editor option available in project explorer for my Eclipse Product.

Comment: You might be able to do this using the [org.eclipse.ui.activities extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_activities.html) but it will require quite a bit of research.

Comment: I have tried using following code in plugin.xml file, It' hiding collapse all and Link with editor option but i am still not able to hide View menu option.

Comment: <property
                  name="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.hideAvailableExtensionsTab"
                  value="true"/> Full code: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp